# List elements merging together?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar in my header and when the page is loading the elements merge together [image: Evidence]

What it should look like: [image: Evidence]
And I have no idea why. It doesn't happen in IE or Firefox, only chrome.

CSS regarding the header:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7.5%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #708090;
}
#headerTitle {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#headerTitleText {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#headerList {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.headerListButton {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.headerListText {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.headerListButton:hover {
    background-color: #616F7E;
}    
#current {
    background-color: #616F7E;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

All HTML regarding the header:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="headerTitle">
            <h1 id="headerTitleText">WIP</h1>
        </div>
        <ul id="headerList">
            <li class="headerListButton"><a href="index.php" class="headerListText">Home</a></li>
            <li class="headerListButton" id="current"><a href="about.html" class="headerListText">About</a></li>
            <li class="headerListButton"><a href="archives.html" class="headerListText">Archives</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Is it a chrome error? After refreshing it gets fixed, it's only when a page is first loaded that it happens. Maybe I should use javascript to automatically refresh the page on load (but how would it know if it's been refreshed already?)

Comment: do not refresh the page just to fix this. the last thing i would want as a visitor to your site is for YOU to refresh your page for me

Comment: I know it's a crappy fix but if it's a chrome error then it would only be temporary.

Comment: I can almost assure you it's not a chrome bug, but I haven't had a chance to see what the problem might be and your image doesn't show me anything to work with - the list items look fine there

Comment: I have added a comment showing what it should look like.

Comment: Temporary fix might be to specify padding in px for `.headerListText`: http://jsbin.com/retumi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I don't really like to use px in any of my code